# External signing PDF with iTextSharp (SignDeferred) - Invalid Signature Problem (altered/corrupted document)

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, digital-signature

The goal is to implement a PDF signing process in which the server provides the hash to be signed to the client on request. The client then signs the given hash using a private key obtained from a smart card through a PKCS#11 interface. The signature is then sent back to the server for attaching into the PDF file using iTextSharp 5.5.4.

On reviewing the signature in Acrobat Reader, it gives me the error **"The document has been altered or corrupted since the signature was applied"**.

[image: Invalid Signature's Image]

Here is the method i used to calculate hash on the server.

```
 public byte[] GetHashToSign(byte[] unsignedPdfBytes, out string signatureFieldName, out byte[] tempFile)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdfBytes))
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);

                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, stream, '\0');
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                signatureFieldName = appearance.FieldName;

                MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 30000);
                result = SHA256Managed.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());
                tempFile = stream.ToArray();

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

After the client signs the given hash, i embed signed hash to pdf on the server. Here is the method i used to embed signed hash.

```
 public void EmbedSignature(byte[] tempPdfBytes, string signatureFieldName, byte[] signedBytes, string signedPdfPath)
    {
        using (PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(tempPdfBytes))
        {
            using (FileStream os = File.OpenWrite(signedPdfPath))
            {
                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new MyExternalSignatureContainer(signedBytes);
                MakeSignature.SignDeferred(pdfReader, signatureFieldName, os, external);
            }
        }
    }
```

On the other hand, when i use the SHA-1, i did not get any error. Acrobat Reader verifies the signature as follows. But i have to use SHA256.

[image: Valid Signature's Image]

Here is the method i used to calculate hash with SHA-1 on the server.

```
    public byte[] GetHashToSign(byte[] unsignedPdfBytes, out string signatureFieldName, out byte[] tempFile)
    {
        byte[] result = null;
        using (PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(unsignedPdfBytes))
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                IExternalSignatureContainer external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);

                PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, stream, '\0');
                PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                signatureFieldName = appearance.FieldName;

                MakeSignature.SignExternalContainer(appearance, external, 30000);
                result = SHA1Managed.Create().ComputeHash(appearance.GetRangeStream());
                tempFile = stream.ToArray();

            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

EDIT: [Signed PDF - Invalid signature with SHA256](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mf7WHI06TKE9dRb4u8arIGe_usRr4bog/view?usp=sharing)

[Signed PDF - valid signature with SHA1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1JAOe1HwmPu8Ba1Gj0kkSLEG3dhBroz9c/view?usp=sharing)

I research all related entries but I did not get any result to handle this problem.
What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Please share an example PDF signed by your code to analyze the issue.

Comment: One question, though: You say *"The client then signs the given hash using a private key obtained from a smart card through a PKCS#11 interface."* - has this code also been adapted to process a SHA256 hash instead of a SHA1 hash?

Comment: thanks for your answer,i added the signed pdfs.

Comment: And i use SHA 256 algorithms to sign with smart card through a PKCS#11 interface.

Comment: Thanks for the files. I should have seen the issue in the code but analyzing the files finally made them leap to my eye. I'll write an answer.

Comment: Thanks, waiting for your answer.

Comment: See my answer, there is more to change in your client code than only switching hash algorithms, the hash returned from the server has to be used differently.

Answer (score 0):

## In Short

There are different sub-types of PDF signatures which have different requirements on the signature to embed. In your switch away from SHA1 usage you change the type and, therefore, not only have to replace SHA1 by SHA256 everywhere, you also have to generate your signature containers differently.

## In Detail

You used to generate PDF signatures of subtype **adbe.pkcs7.sha1**:

```
external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_SHA1);
```

This subtype is defined as:

> The **SHA1** digest of the document’s byte range shall be encapsulated in the CMS SignedData field with ContentInfo of type Data. The digest of that SignedData shall be incorporated as the normal CMS digest. The value *adbe.pkcs7.sha1* for the **SubFilter** key has been deprecated with PDF 2.0. To support backward compatibility, PDF readers should process this value for this key, but PDF writers shall not use this value.

*(ISO 32000-2 section 12.8.3.3 "CMS (PKCS #7) signatures")*

As SHA1 in this subtype is used without alternative, you must use a different subtype when replacing SHA1 by SHA256. Furthermore, this subtype is deprecated, so there is even more cause to switch.

You chose to switch to the subtype **ETSI.CAdES.detached**:

```
external = new ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, PdfName.ETSI_CADES_DETACHED);
```

This subtype is specified as:

> #### 12.8.3.4.2 Signature dictionary for PAdES signatures
>
> When the **SubFilter** value is *ETSI.CAdES.detached*, the value of **Contents** shall be a DER-encoded CMS SignedData binary data object containing the signature. The signature dictionary shall follow the specification given in 12.7.5.5, "Signature fields" with the following additional restrictions/constraints:
>
> - The **ByteRange** shall cover the entire file, including the signature dictionary but excluding the **Contents** entry.
> - The signature dictionary shall not contain a **Cert** entry.
> - Either the time of signing may be indicated by the value of the **M** entry in the signature dictionary or the signing-time attribute may be used, but not both.
>
> #### 12.8.3.4.3 Attributes for PAdES signatures
>
> The attributes in the SignedData object used as the value of the signature dictionary **Contents** key shall obey the following rules:
>
> a) content-type: shall be present and shall always have the value "id-data".
>
> b) Signature timestamp: A timestamp from a trusted timestamp server should be present as a unsigned attribute. The timestamp should be applied on the digital signature immediately after the signature is created so the timestamp specifies a time as close as possible to the time at which the document was signed. The rules from clause 5.3 in ETSI EN 319 122-1 shall apply.
>
> c) content timestamp: may be present. If the content timestamp attribute is present, it shall be used in the same way as defined in clause 5.2.8 in ETSI EN 319 122-1.
>
> d) exactly one single SignerInfo attribute shall be present.
>
> e) message-digest: shall be present and shall be used as defined in CMS (*Internet RFC 5652*).
>
> f) signing-certificate or signing-certificate-v2: shall be used as a signed attribute as described in the ESS signing-certificate attribute or as described in the ESS signing-certificate-v2 attribute as defined in clause 5.2.2 in ETSI EN 319 122-1. The details of the signing certificate attribute can be found in *Internet RFC 5035*.
>
> g) signing-time: may be present. If present, it contains a UTC time. If the signing-time attribute is present, the time of signing shall not be indicated by the value of the M entry in the signature dictionary.
>
> h) signer-location, as defined in clause 5.2.5 in ETSI EN 319 122-1, may be present. In such a case, the Location entry in the signature dictionary shall not be present.
>
> i) these attributes shall not be used: counter-signature, content-reference, content-identifier, and content-hints.
>
> j) signer-attributes-v2: may be used and shall follow the definition given in clause 5.2.6.1 of ETSI EN 319 122-1.
>
> k) Unsigned signature attributes not explicitly noted here may be ignored.

*(ISO 32000-2 section 12.8.3.4 "CAdES signatures as used in PDF")*

As you see, the **ETSI.CAdES.detached** subtype has far more specific requirements than the deprecated **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** subtype. The main difference is, though,

- that in **adbe.pkcs7.sha1** the SHA1 digest of the signed byte ranges is the message signed by the signature container, and this message is encapsulated therein
- while in **ETSI.CAdES.detached** the signed byte ranges themselves are signed directly by the signature container but are not encapsulated therein.

Thus, you do not merely have to switch the hashing algorithm in your client side code but you also have to use the hash value returned from your `GetHashToSign` method differently, not anymore as abstract data message to sign but instead already as the hash of the data to sign.

In your example "invalid signature with SHA256.pdf" the hash of the signed byte ranges still is used as abstract message to sign which is why it's invalid.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, as i understand, you told me to change the codes on the client side. Is that the only problem? Are there any problems with itextsharp's codes?

Comment: It looks all right, in particular as the previous version did work and you only switched hash algorithm and subfilter. If things don't immediately work after client side update, try the subfilter **adbe.pkcs7.detached**. It is similar to **ETSI.CAdES.detached**, merely with less requirements to the CMS signature container.

Comment: I have one more question. 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511383/signature-is-invalid-for-pdf-file-with-itext 

I also examined your answer to the question here. I have the same problem. In your answer there, you said there was a problem with the hash method. (Getting hash of signature field) As far as I understand, I get a hash in the same way as the person asking the question. There's no problem with my hash method, right? I couldn't understand clearly this question's answer.

Comment: *"[stackoverflow.com/questions/49511383/…](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49511383/1729265) I also examined your answer to the question here. I have the same problem."* - You're computing the hash of `appearance.GetRangeStream()`. That is correct. The OP of that other question calculated the hash over the complete file instead. That was wrong. Thus, you don't have the same problem; maybe you have the same symptoms but a different cause.